# Postgres subquery execution steps

Tags: postgresql, subquery, query-optimization

Suppose I have a query which says

```
Select * from ( 
   select coalesce(mytable.created_date,mytable1.created_date) as created_date,...
   from mytable 
   left join mytable1 ON (mytable.id=mytable1.id)
   --Other Joins and tables here
) as foo
where created_date > CURRENT_DATE
```

Will Postgres select only the rows where `created_date is > CURRENT_DATE` for inner query joins where I am joining many tables?

Or will it take all rows from `mytable` and make joins with other tables on inner query, then check for `created_date > CURRENT_DATE`.

Is my previous query the same as

```
select coalesce(mytable.created_date,mytable1.created_date),... from mytable 
    left join mytable1 ON (mytable.id=mytable1.id)
    --Other Joins and tables here 
WHERE 
    coalesce(mytable.created_date,mytable1.created_date) > CURRENT_DATE
```

Comment: You should run an [**EXPLAIN**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-explain.html) and see what Postgres is doing to bring you the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see when you use `EXPLAIN`, the optimizer can “flatten” such subqueries, so that the execution plans for these two queries will be the same.

In other words, the optimizer is able to push the `WHERE` condition into the subquery and the join, so that it can be executed first.

Moreover, if `created_date` happens to be a column of `mytable1`, PostgreSQL will deduce that `created_date` can never be NULL and perform an inner join rather than an outer join.